# Resharper refactoring creating static methods

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, resharper-8.0

When you refactor a method using Resharper 8 and the method arguments do not depend on instance variables of the class, a static method is constructed.  However, an instance method could also have been created.

Is a static method created for performance reasons?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. Here’s what the MSDN documentation has to say about it:

> Members that do not access instance data or call instance methods can
>   be marked as static (Shared in Visual Basic). After you mark the
>   methods as static, the compiler will emit nonvirtual call sites to
>   these members. Emitting nonvirtual call sites will prevent a check at
>   runtime for each call that makes sure that the current object pointer
>   is non-null. This can achieve a measurable performance gain for
>   performance-sensitive code. In some cases, the failure to access the
>   current object instance represents a correctness issue.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245046.aspx